# Pandas operations on selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to standardize certain columns in my pandas dataframe.

```
dfTest = pd.DataFrame({
           'A':[14.00,90.20,90.95,96.27,91.21],
           'B':[103.02,107.26,110.35,114.23,114.68], 
           'C':['big','small','big','small','small']
         })
```

This does not work as only a single index can be set. In case only a single column like 'A' is selected sklearn emits several deprecation warnings

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
dfTest['A_scaled', 'B_scaled'] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A', 'B']])
dfTest
```

How could I achieve something like that?

Comment: Sorry do you mean `dfTest[['A_scaled', 'B_scaled']] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A', 'B']])`?

Comment: or perhaps in the general case `dfTest[['A','B']].apply(scaler.fit_transform)`

Comment: In fact what I really would like that column 'A' is replaced by the newly created scaled column.

Comment: shouldn't my first code snippet work?

Comment: Indeed that works just fine. But if instead of a concat a replacement of the original columns should take place - how can I achieve that?

Comment: Same semantics : `dfTest[['A', 'B']] = scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A', 'B']])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the scaled columns to the original `DF` as shown:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_data = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.fit_transform(dfTest[['A', 'B']]), 
                           columns=['A_scaled', 'B_scaled'])

pd.concat([dfTest, scaled_data], axis=1)
```

[image]